# Read a json key from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm new to jQuery, I tried searching in this forum but couldn't find a solution.

I have json data in the external file. It looks something like this:

```
"products": {
  "Product A": {
    "Type 1": {
      "subtype": {
        "*config*": [{"layoutName": "1 x 13", "layoutModules": 13},
                    {"layoutName": "2 x 13", "layoutModules": 13}]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to display product names (i.e. 'Product A' and 'Product B'). Here is my jQuery code:

```
  $.getJSON('js/products.json', function(data) {
    for (var i in data.products) {
      output=JSON.stringify(data.products.keys[i]);
    }
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=output;
  });
```

But I am not able to get the required data. I get this error in the browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Product A' of undefined.

Can any one tell me what I doing wrong?

Comment: your json object is not valid on your question. If you copy pasted it pleace recheck and here is the fixed version http://fiddle.jshell.net/1x0Lyxan/1/

Comment: it should probably be just `output=JSON.stringify(data.products[i]);`

Comment: Thanks @Azadrum for the response. I edited the json code. Copied the code exactly. It has been validated with JSONLint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here. First of all, your JSON data structure is malformed. Also, please take a look at [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for proper usage of the `for.. in` loop. Keep in mind also that you probably want to do a string concatenation in your `for..in` loop.

Take a look at these codes to see if they do what you want. (I have to convert your `Product A` and `Product B` into an array within the JSON object.)

```js
data = 
{"products":
    [{"Product A":
         {"Type 1":
               {"subType":[{"layoutName":"1 x 13","layoutModules":13}]}
         }
    },
    {"Product B":
         {"Type 1":
               {"subType":[{"layoutName":"2 x 13","layoutModules":13}]}
         }
    }]
};

var content = "";
for(property in data)
    for(product in data[property]) 
        content += Object.keys(data[property][product])[0] + ", ";

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @isim Looks like you got it. I copied the same code but it prints Type1 and Type1(i.e 2nd level keys). I will try to tweak the for..in loop to get the results.

Comment: Deeply nested JSON object is always tricky. Try to use `console.log()` to help you with debugging.